# VBScript (.vbs) Not Passing Privileges to Subordinate VBS routine

Tags: vbscript, citrix

I have a master VB Script routine (‘parent’) that is used to schedule and start many other individual VB Script routines (‘child/ren’) at various times of the day and various days of the week.  This ‘parent’ script has been in use since 2000 – we just keep adding ‘child’ jobs to it as needed.  It runs under a super-user type account login that is used exclusively for this purpose and that user has all the rights/privileges needed.

Recently we added a Citrix file storage system to our network that requires its own login from the super-user account in order to establish a mapped drive.  That drive is visible to the account logged in with no issues.

During some testing recently I ran into a problem where I found that when the ‘child’ routine was started directly, (by double-clicking on the ‘child’ VBS file itself for example) it runs fine, but when it is initiated by the ‘parent’ routine it fails to ‘find’ the new mapped drive.

The line of code where the 'path not found' error occurs is:

```
Set varDataFolder  = fso.GetFolder("U:\Shared With Me\FTPROOT\xxxxx\")
```

We are running on a 2.5 GHz Intel Xeon processor, with a Windows 2012 R2 O/S.

I’m trying to determine what additional commands I may need to add to our ‘parent’ script to force it to start any ‘child’ script with the same rights and privileges as the parent.

If I execute the ‘child’ routine from a BAT file the job runs fine and can find the mapped drive.  (Side note, if I execute the BAT file from the ‘parent’ VBS routine, the ‘child’ routine still dies, not finding the mapped drive.)

All of this testing is while logged in as the super-user, so the only reason I can think that this is happening is that the ‘parent’ VBS routine does not pass all of its privileges to the ‘child’ routine/s when they are started.  Until dealing with this new mapped drive system it hasn’t been a problem – hasn’t even been noticed that this might be the case.

This same error occurs when attempting to run these same tests from a different server as well.